# Cannot apply AWS policy to group, only to user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudsearch

I am trying to set up permissions on a CloudSearch domain.

This policy works:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::55555555:user/SearchUser"
      },
      "Action": "cloudsearch:*"
    }
  ]
}
```

This does not:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::55555555:group/SearchGroup"
      },
      "Action": "cloudsearch:*"
    }
  ]
}
```

The only difference is user/SearchUser vs group/SearchGroup

When I try to apply the latter it just gives me an error:

> Error setting policy:
>   [{"Version":"2012-10-17","Statement":[{"Effect":"Allow","Principal":{"AWS":"arn:aws:iam::55555555:group/SearchGroup"},"Action":"cloudsearch:*"}]}]

Any ideas on why the policy works for a user but not a group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Groups are not supported.

> **Specifying a Principal**
>
> You specify a principal using the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the
>   AWS account, IAM user, IAM role, federated user, or assumed-role user.
>   *You cannot specify IAM groups as principals.*

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Principal

Comment: Any idea how best to accomplish what I'm trying -- I basically want that group and only that group to access the particular CloudSearch domain.  I can attach a policy to the group, but do I think "deny all" on the CloudSearch object's policy?